# Smaller client results in a very slow query

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, postgresql-9.6

I am testing a query on PostgreSQL 9.6 on a very small tenant and a big one (within the same database, schema, tables). The query is super slow on a small client, which is quite surprising as I would expect otherwise.

The query plans:

Small - https://explain.depesz.com/s/mnlD

Large - https://explain.depesz.com/s/JB85

The noticeable difference between the queries is that the smaller one uses a *Nested loop* over  a *Hash join* and I did find that a query planner might do that when the tables are "small".

I am not suggesting that there is a problem with the planner, the query is far from perfect but clearly, if a big client is queried x times quicker I would assume that the smaller one should not be a problem. How could I rectify this?

I tried running `vacuum analyze` on all involved tables but it did not help.

I am aware there have been three new major versions of PostgreSQL but 9.6 is officially still supported so it does not explain or justify the issue.

Comment: 1) I suggest you test with version 12 anyway to see if there's any improvement. Lots of improvements to JSONB handling and performance improvements in the query planner have been made in recent versions. 2) How is your JSONB data indexed? 3) Please edit your question to include table definitions including indexes.

Comment: "*is officially still supported so it does not explain or justify the issue*" just because a version is still supported, doesn't mean it doesn't have bug or later versions don't improve performance. I agree it doesn't "explain" the issue, but it could very well "justify" it, if later versions improved the query optimizer in a way that it can deal better with your specific situation.